# Highchart - How do I change the colour of the baseline of the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

How do I change the colour of the baseline of the chart? I can't seem to find a attribute for that in this link - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Axis/highcharts_Axis.htm? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xAxis: {
    lineColor: "#F2F2F2",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
yAxis: {
    plotLines:[{
        color: '#ff0000',
        width:2
    }]
}
```

documentation: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotLines